# UK Visitor Visa refused under paragraphs V4.2 (a), (c) of the Immigration Rules - incorrect decision

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

My visa has been refused with no right of appeal or right to administrative review, but the this is not clear to me, it has been rejected last time and I had explained all the reason for and provided all required proof this time, but this response came back in less than a week. Is this normal ?

I feel this is not fair and wanted to ask if there's any way to appeal this ?

[image: Refusal]

Comment: I submitted by application on the 9th and the refusal arrived the next day within less than 24 hours. I had provided all my current land, property proof on my country and also my savings that I have. 

Since I'm retired and have time now, this was the opportunity for me to to visit my family in UK. I do have my own allowance, interest from my savings and I also get sent funds from family members abroad while looking after their property - on the income , I section i had rounded off £3600 off to £4000 and is shown on my statement.

Comment: A visitor visa is a privilege, not a right. How many times have you been refused previously and over what period? How long was your proposed visit? How many months’ worth of bank statements did you provide? Why did you round up £3,600 by 10% when it appears your statements didn’t support a higher amount? How will you continue to look after property in your country of residence and get income for doing so if you are visiting the UK? You too could arrange for someone to look after your own property, which diminishes the value of it as a compelling tie/reason for you to leave the UK

Answer (score 6):

The refusal is perfectly fair and the reasons for it are stated clearly.

Based on the information in the refusal letter, your personal circumstances do not meet the ‘genuine visitor’ requirements of the Immigration Rules pertaining to visitor visas.

> V 4.2. The applicant must satisfy the decision maker that they are a genuine visitor, which means the applicant:

> (a) will leave the UK at the end of their visit; and

> (c) is genuinely seeking entry or stay for a purpose that is permitted under the Visitor route as set out in Appendix Visitor: Permitted Activities and at V >13.3

https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor

You have no ties to your country of residence. You have family in the UK. The financial information you presented did not show you have sufficient, credible, means to make the trip. Consequently, UKVI has concluded that there is a risk you would not leave the UK.

Your latest refusal mentions previous refusal(s). Repeated attempts to get a visitor visa are doomed to failure *unless your personal circumstances change*. There is no path for appeal and judicial reviews of visitor applications are costly and seldom, if ever, reach the hearing stage. What this adds up to is there's nothing to be done by way of judicial remedy. Unless those circumstances change dramatically, you will / have already entered a tail spin of serial refusals that will lead precisely nowhere.

Answer (score 5):

> I feel this is not fair and wanted to ask if there's any way to appeal

You may feel that way, but the immigration officer job is just not made to be fair. What they want is to limit people settling in the country illegally. And they do that by assessing your ties to your home/residence country (more = better), and your eventual ties to the UK (**usually** less = better)

If they note that you don't have any assets (like home, car...) owned in your name, nor do you have remaining family is a dark red flag and suggests you would abscond and remain in the UK after the visa expired, because they're asking themselves, what would entice you to go back to Nepal after your visit to the UK, and in their thinking nothing, as your family is in the UK.

This [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/92122/118049) goes into way more details about your refusal

The statement that the income stated is not reflected in your bank statement is also a really bad look

**Please** read this [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/66105/118049) about bank statements, this is a wealth of information